# Find an example of $p$-solvable group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, solvable-groups

This is an definition about $p$-solvable. https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/P-solvable_group.

I can't find examples of them in any book, maybe I haven't read enough books. More,  I saw that there was writing "a finite group is solvable if and only if it is p-solvable for every prime $p$". I have not yet thought about why it is like that.

Also, is the order of $p$-solvable anything special?

Comment: How about groups of size $p$? Or Abelian groups?

Comment: How about $C_7 \times A_5$? It is $7$-solvable.